# Is set of matrices form $M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb R)$ with rank 1 is closed or open?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology

> Is set of matrices form $M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb R)$ with rank 1 is closed or open ?

I know that $M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb R)$ can be viewed as $\mathbb R^9$ with the euclidean norm on it.

But I do not know any continous function which determined by rank.

So I could not argue how to say open set or closed set.

**Please give me just hint.**

I wanted to solve problem.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

Consider $$T_n=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{n}&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix},$$
to prove that it's not closed and $$Q_n=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\frac{1}{n}&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix},$$
to prove that it's not open.

Comment: SO given set is not closed as 0 matrix is limit of that set. Similary We can show that its complement is not closed so Not open.THanks a lot

Comment: @SRJ: yes exactly :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you perturb the entries of a rank 1 matrix, does it remain rank 1?

(In other words, do points near a given point in your set still lie in your set?)

Comment: Nice hint for half the question.