# Is the set of rank 1 matrices positive matrices that sum to $1$ closed?

Tags: general-topology, matrix-rank, weak-topology

This question arises from my exploratory research on causality.

Let $M=\{ A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n} : \forall i,j~A_{i,j}\geq 0,\sum_{i,j} A_{i,j} = 1 \}$ be the simplex of matrices of size $n\times n$. We equip this set with the weakest topology that makes any linear $f:M\to\mathbb R$ continuous. I am wondering about if the following is true or not.

> Is the set of rank $1$ matrices in $M$ a closed set ?

I'm not sure on how to start, any idea is welcome. I cannot use the response in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3329922/is-set-of-matrices-form-m-3-times-3-mathbb-r-with-rank-1-is-closed-or-open), so it feels like if it is closed, the fact that matrices sum to $1$ is relevant.

I would also be very interested in knowing if the set of rank $1$ matrices of $M$ is measurable in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the above topology, and also if any answer to those would change if the topology was the one induced by a matrix norm.

Comment: A potentially useless comment, but my first instinct would be in fact to use that result: can you show that the intersection of closed sets is closed in your topology, and if so, can you show your set $M$ is closed? Then you're done, right?

Comment: @DerekAllums Well, for sure $M$ is closed, the question is more about the subset of $M$ that consists of rank $1$ matrices. Now I'm not sure if this can be expressed as the intersection of some closed sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is closed.
Let $N$ be the set of non-negative vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that sum to $1$.  Note that $N$ is compact.  Then $$M=\{uv^t|u,v\in N\}$$
Let $e$ be the vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with all $1$s.  If $\{A_i\in M\}$ is Cauchy, then so is $\{A_i e\}$ and $\{e^tA_i\}$, so their component $u_i$ and $v_i$ have limits in $N$.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you very much. If I understand correctly this shows that if $A_i=u_i v_i^T$, then $u_i\to u$ and $v_i\to v$. This alone doesn't show (directly) that $A=u v^T$ but we can conclude easily from the fact that $e_k A_i e_\ell^T=u_{ik} v_{i\ell}\to u_k v_\ell$ that $A=u v^T$. Is that correct ?

Comment: I think so.  But I don't know about various topilogies.

Comment: Well all functions $A\to a^T A b$ are continuous so we are fine.